# SQL: Creating an aggregated table from a 2-column data source

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I have a table within a database, and I want to aggregate the questions and answers within them into a more readable data table. The source table

```
+-----+----------------+----------------------------+----------------+
| QID | Date Submitted |          Question          |     Answer     |
+-----+----------------+----------------------------+----------------+
|   0 | 08/04/2021     | companyName                | Yaneev         |
|   1 | 08/04/2021     | humanRightPolicy           | George Micheal |
|   2 | 08/04/2021     | accountManagerMobileNumber | 7474236843     |
|   3 | 08/04/2021     | swiftCode                  | AOEU326        |
|   4 | 03/04/2021     | companyName                | Eimbee         |
|   5 | 03/04/2021     | humanRightPolicy           | Revvie George  |
|   6 | 03/04/2021     | accountManagerMobileNumber | 7475123843     |
|   7 | 03/04/2021     | swiftCode                  | AOEU324        |
|   8 | 04/04/2021     | companyName                | Yaneev         |
|   9 | 04/04/2021     | humanRightPolicy           | Mark Fox       |
|  10 | 04/04/2021     | accountManagerMobileNumber | 74742121231    |
|  11 | 04/04/2021     | swiftCode                  | 124eoKK        |
+-----+----------------+----------------------------+----------------+
```

And what I want the 'destination' table to look like

```
+--------------+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------+
| Company Name | humanRightsPolicy | accountManagerMobileNumber | swiftCode |
+--------------+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------+
| Yaneev       | George Micheal    |                 7474236843 | AOEU326   |
| Eimbee       | Revvie George     |                 7475123843 | AOEU324   |
+--------------+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------+
```

I'd also like to know what kind of operation this is, as I feel that it's something that isn't new in any way.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  If your table does not have a column that specifies the ordering of the row, you cannot do what you want because the ordering of the data is not defined.

Comment: Show us different names, and answers.

Comment: @jarlh, added example questions and answers. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  Let me assume that you have an ordering column.  With such a column, you can assign a group to each set of rows for the same company and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when question = 'Company Name' then answer end) as company_name,
       max(case when question = 'Q1' then answer end) as q1,
       max(case when question = 'Q2' then answer end) as q2,
       max(case when question = 'Q3' then answer end) as q3       
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when question = 'Company Name' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Note that this answers the question that you asked, where all the questions are known -- so the result columns are all known.  If you don't know the questions in advance, you need to use dynamic SQL (i.e. construct the query as a string and then execute it).  How to do that depends entirely on the database you are using.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a subquery:

```
select max(case when question = 'Company Name' then answer end) as company_name,
       max(case when question = 'Q1' then answer end) as q1,
       max(case when question = 'Q2' then answer end) as q2,
       max(case when question = 'Q3' then answer end) as q3       
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.question = 'Company Name' and
                    t2.<ordering col> <= t.<ordering col>
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: Hi, there is an ordering column, just omitted for clarity. The issue here is that the answers are mostly strings, so the max() operator won't work on those. I'll try to use this 'case when' approach anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Wiki . . . Of course `max()` works on strings.  Where do people get the idea that it doesn't?  You are definitely not the first person with that misconception.

Comment: I come from a programming background - SQL is very new to me. Javascript Math.max() only operates on numbers - hence the (wrongful) assumption!

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, I'm using an older verison of MySQL that doesn't support the OVER() window function. What would be the alternative?

Comment: @Wiki . . . You should tag with the database you are using.  I edited the answer with an alternative.